# How to change display text in bigcommerce?

Tags: html, bigcommerce

Do anyone have an idea on how to change the display text in bigcommerce? I want to rename "Create an Account" to " Sign up" in the top menu. I had look into the back end codes of it but i am not sure on where to find the exact text and edit it. The code in bigcommerce are far different from the usual html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved my problem, i just inserted this script and it overlap the "Create an account" with "Sign Up"

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready( function() {
     $("a:contains('Create an account')").text('Sign up');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In Bigcommerce the actually code will depend on how your template has been built. That said, this will typically be found in the TopMenu.html Panel.

Usually the "Sign in or Create an Account" text is dynamically inserted via a shortcode. If that is the case you will need to use jquery/javascript to change the text. It might look something like the following.

```
jQuery('.top-menu .create-account a').text('Sign Up');
```

We would need your specific code to be able to offer more guidance.